# Disable drag and sort features on kanban columns view in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I'm making a kanban view in Odoo 9 to display my model in columns based in a Many2one field.

I've created my kanban view like this:

```
<kanban create="false" edit="false" delete="false" quick_create="false" default_group_by="resource_id">
```

I only want this view for read only, I don't want to edit or create because I have another view to do it. It's like a dashboard.

The problem is that I want to disable the drag and drop and sortable feature for the columns. I see that the `kanban_view.js` file set the sortable and draggable options by default in the `render_grouped` function.

Does anyone know how to disable those features for columns? Or, is there any other way to display my records by columns in a kanban view?

Answer (score 2):

To Disable Drag and Drop of Kanban View  records we need to modify at web_kanban module.

Path : web_kanban/static/src/js
File : kanban_view.js
Modification : Search for the below code

```
var record_options = _.extend(this.record_options, {
        draggable: draggable,
    });
```

Then add

```
draggable = false
```

**just above given block of code** like,

```
draggable = false [Note : This is the newly added line]

var record_options = _.extend(this.record_options, 
    {
        draggable: draggable,
    });
```

Comment: In that case one could also write `var record_options = _.extend(this.record_options, { draggable: false });` instead of adding the additional line.

Comment: Hi SaschaM78, I already tried the same before posting, it was not working, so i went with the code posted above to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To this day, there is no parameter to do this. So in your new module, create a JS extension on KanbanView, override render() and disable the sortable there. Here is the complete .js code for Odoo 10 which should be similar for v9:

```
odoo.define('my_module.board', function(require) {
  "use strict";

  var core = require('web.core');
  var KanbanView = require('web_kanban.KanbanView');

  var MyBoard = KanbanView.extend({
    render: function() {
      this._super.apply(this, arguments);
      this.$el.sortable('option', 'disabled', true);
      this.$('.o_kanban_header').css('cursor', 'auto');
    }
  });

  return MyBoard;
});
```

P.S.: I strongly advise against modifying Odoo base code unless you don't plan on updating.

Answer (score 0):

In odoo 13 you can add the `records_draggable` attribute to your `<kanban>` tag:

```xml
<kanban records_draggable="false"></kanban>
```

For more check the [kanban view](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/views.html#kanban) section in the documentation