# How to disable drag and drop in a Kanban view for a specific model in Odoo 10?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I have a Kanban view for a model named *'daily.source.reivew'* in **Odoo10**. Currently, the drag and drop feature is enabled and with drag and drop I can change records between columns (states) of Kanban view. But I want to disable this feature for Kanban view of a specific model not other models of my module.

I tried [Disable drag and sort features on kanban columns view in Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081060/disable-drag-and-sort-features-on-kanban-columns-view-in-odoo/44187090#44187090) JavaScript code but it didn't effected.

How can I use JavaScript code or any options in XML to disable drag and drop in my Kanban view in Odoo 10?

Comment: Try changing the field which represents the column to read only if you dont want to move it at all

Comment: I don't want to drag records from one column to another, but records from kanban view should be clickable and upon clicking on card the form view should be open. Although, I didn't get your point by changing fields to read only.